# Data Looping from MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem of data looping here. Basically the questions keep looping whenever there are answers for it . I am trying to display something like :

```
Question 
Answer 1  
Answer 2 
Answer 3
```

instead of

```
Question 
Answer 1

Question
Answer 2

Question
Answer 3
```

Anyone know how to solve this ?

```
<?php
$auctionSurvey = "SELECT questions.question_id, answers.question_id, answers.survey_id, question_body, answer_body FROM questions
                  INNER JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.question_id
                  WHERE answers.survey_id='1'";
$aucResult = mysql_query($auctionSurvey) or die (mysql_error());

while ($auctionRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($aucResult)) {
    echo $auctionRow['question_body'] . $auctionRow['answer_body'];
}
```

Comment: Because that's how `JOIN`s work. If your data maps between tables A and B in an n:m relationship you'll have n copies of B's data, m copies of A's data, and n*m total rows. You have to write the logic in PHP to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$questionId = 0;
while($auctionRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($aucResult)){
   if($auctionRow['question_id'] != $questionId){
        echo $auctionRow['question_body'];
        $questionId = $auctionRow['question_id'];
   }  
   echo $auctionRow['answer_body'];
}
```

Add some HTML to format it and that should work for ya.

Edit: Proof: http://ideone.com/Gkq2hd

Comment: This only displays answer_body right? How do I actually make the questions don't loop?

Question Answer 1 Answer 2 Answer 3 
instead of 
Question Answer 1 Question Answer 2 ...

Comment: Did you try it? Did you even read the code? You just asked your question again in response to my answer.

Comment: Yeah I did try . It only shows the answers. I tried echoing question_body but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, it should work, so there must be another issue with your code. In your while() loop, do a var_dump($auctionRow); - what is in your array?

Comment: I tried echo $auctionRow['question_body'] then var_dump($auctionRow) in the while loop. Didn't work either.

Comment: http://ideone.com/Gkq2hd

It works fine for me. If you didn't even see anything with a var_dump then the problem is in your query, which is not the problem you described in your question. PS: If people ask you "what" you saw and you respond "it didn't work" they're going to stop trying to help.

Comment: I apologize for the unclear description. Basically this is how it goes now. When I echo question_body in the while loop, the result is as per the one in my question. I added vardump in the while loop, the output is things like this Auction2array(4) { ["question_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["survey_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["question_body"]=> string(8) .

Comment: Go look at the fiddle I posted, the code works fine. Your var_dump looks fine too (with the exception of your id being a string, wth?). Update with your new code if it's not working.